# BinaryFormatter fails on int[,]

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

In my program I am serializing an int array with two dimensions. It appears to serialize correctly, but upon deserializing it throws a exception with the message:

"Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization"

I am using the BinaryFormatter type to do the serialization/deserialization. I commented out the various fields on the class in turn, and it was an instance of int[,] that caused the failure. What is causing this type to make the deserialization fail? Is there another type that is more suitable?

Edit: Here is an example of the relevant sections of code:

Deserialization:

```
int bytesRead = Ssl.EndRead(asyncResult);    
int bytesToRead = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataBuffer, 0);
dataBuffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
Ssl.Read(dataBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dataBuffer);

//Add the message to the queue and signal that it is avaible
Message m = (Message)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
```

Serilaization:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(ms, message);
byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();
int length = (int)data.Length;
byte[] count = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
Ssl.Write(count);
Ssl.Write(data);
```

And the class being serialized. The data field is an instance of Tile:

```
[Serializable]
public struct Message
{
    public MessageType Type;
    public Object Data;
}

[Serializable]
public class Tile
{
    [NonSerialized]
    public const int Width = 128;

    [NonSerialized]
    public const int Height = 128;

    public Vector3 Location;
    public int[,] Heightmap;

    public static Tile CreateEmpty(Vector3 location)
    {
        Tile t = new Tile();
        t.Location = location;
        t.Heightmap = new int[Width,Height];
        for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                t.Heightmap[x, y] = 0;
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It'll make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the initial post to include the relevant code sections.

Comment: Does this have the same problem if you just take the output of the serializer and feed it straight into the deserialiser?

Comment: It does not, so the error must be in my handling of the networking. I find this interesting as other smaller messages succeed. I will double check the network code again, and report back. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem: `Ssl.Read(dataBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);` - you appear to be *assuming* that you can read the whole lot in a single call.

Comment: That was indeed the issue! I was unaware the third term was a maximum, and less could returned. Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated. Should I close the question?